# Probability current density of gaussian wavepacket

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, probability

This was the question that was asked in an exam.

> For a gaussian wavepacket $$ \psi(x,t) = Ae^{\frac{x^2}{4a^2}}e^{i(k_0x-\omega_0t)} $$ corresponding to a free particle, (i) Find the probaibility current density and (ii) verify the continuity equation.

My Answer for (i) was $j(x) = \frac{\hbar A^2 k_0e^{x^2/2a^2}}{m}$

Now according to equation of continuity the divergence of probability current density should be zero for this wavefunction.But clearly it is not.Why?

Related: Look at [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/618562/probability-current-calculations) for the formula to calculate probability currents generally

Answer (score 1):

First, note that the state written above is not properly time evolved according to a free-particle Hamiltonian, unless we take $a$ to be time dependent. See e.g. [these lecture notes](https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/jayaprakash.1/631/freegauss.pdf) for an explicit calculation of what $a(t)$ must be.

The continuity equation is
\begin{equation}
\partial_t \rho(x) + \boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot \mathbf{j}(x)=0.
\end{equation}
With $a=a(t)$, the first term does not vanish, as the probability density changes with time. From this, one can see that the divergence of the current can be non-zero if the probability density $\rho$ changes over time.

In your case, the non zero divergence comes from the fact that the gaussian wave packet will spread over time, and so will the density.

Also, I believe there is a typo in the quadratic exponential term in the question and answer,  and it should be $e^{-x^2/2\alpha^2}$ instead. Otherwise the packet is not bounded at infinity but diverges (and is not a gaussian).

Comment: So i can safely say that question was not properly formulated because they should have mentioned that 'a' is a function time.

Comment: I would say so.